# How to copy cell range as table from excel to powerpoint - VBA

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint, range

I cant find any way to do this. What I have now is that it copy the range as an image:

Dim XLApp As Excel.Application
Dim PPSlide As Slide
Set XLApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
XLApp.Range("A1:B17").Select 
XLApp.Selection.CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture

PPSlide.Shapes.Paste.Select

this works like a charm, but is it possible to get it to copy the range as a table instead of picture?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to copy cell range as table from excel to powerpoint - VBA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3840370/how-to-copy-cell-range-as-table-from-excel-to-powerpoint-vba)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. If you write something like this:

```
XLApp.Selection.Copy
PPSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial ppPasteOLEObject
```