# How to copy cell range as table from Excel to PowerPoint - VBA

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I can't find any way to do this. What I have now is that it copy the range as an image:

```
Dim XLApp As Excel.Application 
Dim PPSlide As Slide 

Set XLApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application") 
XLApp.Range("A1:B17").Select 
XLApp.Selection.CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture
PPSlide.Shapes.Paste.Select
```

this works like a charm, but is it possible to get it to copy the range as a table instead of picture?

Comment: Why are you asking the same question twice?

Comment: I'm sorry, but i couldnt log in with the account i posted the last question with, and the markup was a mess in it. So i thought it would be better to ask it again with properly formatted code.

Answer (score 9):

This can be done simply with

```
Dim XLApp As Excel.Application
Dim PPSlide As Slide

Set XLApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
XLApp.Range("A1:B17").Copy
PPSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial DataType:=ppPasteOLEObject, Link:=msoFalse
```

Comment: Can you explain this please? I am not able get this Macro work.

Answer (score 2):

Well, if I was copying it manually, I would probably do a Paste Special and choose "Formatted Text (RTF)" as the type.  I'm sure you can mimic that in VBA.

#### Edit

Aah, here we go.  Do this in your powerpoint:

1. Go to **Insert->Object**
2. Choose your Excel file.  Check the **Link** option.

A link to your XL file is now embedded in your PP file.  When the data in your XL file changes, you can:

1. Update it manually by **Right-Click->Update Link**.
2. Update it automatically by VBA by using something like `ActivePresentation.UpdateLinks`

This is a very different approach than what you were doing first, but I believe it gets you closer to your goal.  It has it own problems, though, but those can be worked out.

Comment: I've tried PPSlide.Selection.PasteExcelTable - but this doesnt work. and also PPSlide.Shapes.PasteExcelTable . Any ideas?


EDIT: I cant record macros in powerpoint, but when I try to do it in word and copy the table from excel the way u suggest I get this code: Selection.PasteAndFormat (wdTableOriginalFormatting) - is there something similar i can use in the powerpoint vba code?

Comment: Hmm, why can't you use the PasteExcelTable methods? What error do you get?

Comment: Compile error: 
Method or data member not found

Is the error i get when I try PPSlide.Selection.PasteExcelTable or PPSlide.Shapes.PasteExcelTable. So i guess the syntax isnt all good then?

Comment: (A little training tip: VBA has a feature called Intellisense which gives you a list of available methods/properties/etc.  In VBA, if you type "PPSlide." you should see a drop-down list of the members of that class. If you don't see what you're looking for, then you're doing it wrong.  Very helpful when you're designing something you've never done before)

Comment: See my Edit above. An alternative approach.

Comment: Thanks for the alternative solution. But I can't get it to work. This is mainly because my excel document I try to link to is empty and have a macro to run on the on open event that creates the content dynamically from an external xml source, and the document is never saved. I wish there would be an easier approach to this problem, but it seems like I may have to try to tweak my macros to get it work this way, if no one else have any other solutions. Thanks for the help, really appreciate it!

Comment: Let me get this straight: You have an xml source document that feeds data to an Excel file that feeds data to a powerpoint? What if you just simulate the powerpoint in Excel? 1 less format to worry about.

Comment: Downvoted (perhaps harshly) given the simplicity of Simon's VBA solution; I found basically the same code at the MrExcel forums (http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/showthread.php?t=376733).

Comment: @Dave Duplantis, I agree that Simon's solution is much simpler that mine (haven't tried it yet, but it should work). However, you're downvoting me because a better solution was posted over 3 months *after* mine. And no one else said anything about it in that entire time.  In your shoes, I would just upvote Simon's solution, make a comment, and leave it at that.

Answer (score 0):

Just needing to figure this out myself. Here's the paste special that worked for me:

```
XLApp.Selection.Copy
PPSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial DataType:=ppPasteDefault
```

I found the full list of special paste options here:

http://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/2014/3/17/copy-paste-an-excel-range-into-powerpoint-with-vba

Answer (score 0):

The above proposed solutions did not work for me as the excel table continued being pasted in powerpoint as a (non-editable) picture.

To directly run the pastespecial 'Keep Source Formatting' button in the commandbar in powerpoint run following code:

```
Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("PasteSourceFormatting")
```

More (but limited) info on Microsoft msdn site: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff862419.aspx

Answer (score -1):

```
Sub abc()

j = 2
Sheets("sheet1").Select

ActiveSheet.Range("a1").Select
ActiveSheet.Range("a65536").Select
lastrow = Selection.End(xlUp).Row

'/// column a
ActiveSheet.Range("a3:a" & lastrow).Select

Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.AutoFilter
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$3:$A$" & lastrow).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="="

Set Rng = ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range

cnt = Rng.Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count - 1

   If cnt = 0 Then
   GoTo label1
   End If

    ActiveSheet.Range("a3:a" & lastrow - 1).Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Copy



    'Selection.EntireRow.Select

'    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    rownum = Selection.Row

'    If rownum = 3 Then
'    Selection.AutoFilter
'    GoTo label1
'    End If

    'Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    'lrow = ActiveSheet.Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row

    lrow = Cells.Find(what:="*", after:=[a1], searchorder:=xlByRows, _
    searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row

    ActiveSheet.Range("a" & lrow + 1).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Selection.Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select

    Selection.EntireRow.Delete
     Application.CutCopyMode = False

label1:
 Selection.AutoFilter

'column b///////////


ActiveSheet.Range("a65536").Select
lastrow = Selection.End(xlUp).Row
ActiveSheet.Range("b3:b" & lastrow).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.AutoFilter
    ActiveSheet.Range("$b$3:$b$" & lastrow).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="="

    Set Rng = ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range

cnt = Rng.Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count - 1

   If cnt = 0 Then
   GoTo label2
   End If

        ActiveSheet.Range("$b$3:$b$" & lastrow - 1).Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Copy

    'Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToLeft)).Select
    '
   ' Selection.EntireRow.Select

    'Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select

'    rownum = Selection.Row
'    If rownum = 3 Then
'    Selection.AutoFilter
'    GoTo label2
'    End If

   ' Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    'lrow = ActiveSheet.Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row

    lrow = Cells.Find(what:="*", after:=[a1], searchorder:=xlByRows, _
    searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row

    ActiveSheet.Range("a" & lrow + 1).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select

    'Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select

'Selection.Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
'
'    Selection.EntireRow.Delete

    ActiveSheet.Range("$b$3:$b$" & lastrow - 1).Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

label2:
     Selection.AutoFilter

    'column c////////////


    ActiveSheet.Range("c65536").Select
lastrow = Selection.End(xlUp).Row
 ActiveSheet.Range("c3:c" & lastrow).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.AutoFilter
    ActiveSheet.Range("$c$3:$c$" & lastrow).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="SG Plus", _
    Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="=Select"

Set Rng = ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range

cnt = Rng.Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count - 1

   If cnt = 0 Then
   GoTo label3
   End If

            ActiveSheet.Range("$c$3:$c$" & lastrow - 1).Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Copy

    'Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
'    Selection.Copy
'    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
'    lrow = activehseet.Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row
'    ActiveSheet.Range("a" & lrow).Select
'    ActiveSheet.Paste
'    Sheets("Sheet1").Select



'    rownum = Selection.Row
'    If rownum = 3 Then
'    Selection.AutoFilter
'    GoTo label3
'    End If

'    Range("a4:a" & lastrow).Select
'    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
'    Selection.EntireRow.Select
'    Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select


            ActiveSheet.Range("$c$3:$c$" & lastrow - 1).Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Select

    Selection.EntireRow.Delete
        Application.CutCopyMode = False


label3:
 Selection.AutoFilter


'column c again/////////////


    ActiveSheet.Range("c65536").Select
lastrow = Selection.End(xlUp).Row

ActiveSheet.Range("c3:c" & lastrow).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.AutoFilter
    ActiveSheet.Range("$c$3:$c$" & lastrow).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="="

    Set Rng = ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range

cnt = Rng.Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count - 1

   If cnt = 0 Then
   GoTo label4
   End If

                ActiveSheet.Range("$c$3:$c$" & lastrow - 1).Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Copy



'    rownum = Selection.Row
'    If rownum = 3 Then
'    Selection.AutoFilter
'    GoTo label4
'    End If
'
'    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
'
'        Range("a4:a" & lastrow).Select
'    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
'
'    Selection.EntireRow.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    'lrow = ActiveSheet.Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row

    lrow = Cells.Find(what:="*", after:=[a1], searchorder:=xlByRows, _
    searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row

    ActiveSheet.Range("a" & lrow + 1).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select

                    ActiveSheet.Range("$c$3:$c$" & lastrow - 1).Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Select

 '   Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select

    Selection.EntireRow.Delete
        Application.CutCopyMode = False

label4:
    Selection.AutoFilter

'//////////////////////////  over  /////////////////////////////



ActiveSheet.Range("a1").Select
For i = 4 To lastrow
Range("a" & i).Select
If Range("a" & i).Value = "MidAmerica" Or Range("a" & i).Value = "Northeast" Or Range("a" & i).Value = "Southeast" Or _
Range("a" & i).Value = "West" Then
GoTo cont
Else

Rows(i).Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Cut
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select

        lrow = Cells.Find(what:="*", after:=[a1], searchorder:=xlByRows, _
    searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row

    Range("a" & lrow + 1).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    j = j + 1
    Sheets("sheet1").Select
       Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
   End If
cont:
Next i


'/////// column b ///////////

ActiveSheet.Range("a1").Select
For i = 4 To lastrow
Range("b" & i).Select
If Range("b" & i).Value = "CA" Or Range("b" & i).Value = "AZ" Then
GoTo cont2
Else

Rows(i).Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Cut
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    lrow = Cells.Find(what:="*", after:=[a1], searchorder:=xlByRows, _
    searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    Range("a" & lrow + 1).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    j = j + 1
    Sheets("sheet1").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
   End If
cont2:
Next i

'///////////column c //////////

ActiveSheet.Range("a1").Select
For i = 4 To lastrow
Range("c" & i).Select
If Range("c" & i).Value = "SG" Then
GoTo cont3
Else

Rows(i).Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Cut
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    lrow = Cells.Find(what:="*", after:=[a1], searchorder:=xlByRows, _
    searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row

    Range("a" & lrow + 1).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    j = j + 1
    Sheets("sheet1").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
   End If
cont3:
Next i

'//////////column l/////////////
ActiveSheet.Range("a1").Select
For i = 4 To lastrow
Range("l" & i).Select
If Range("l" & i).Value <= "01/06/2014" And Range("l" & i).Value >= "01/01/2013" Then
GoTo cont4
Else

Rows(i).Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Cut
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select

        lrow = Cells.Find(what:="*", after:=[a1], searchorder:=xlByRows, _
    searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row

    Range("a" & lrow + 1).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    j = j + 1
    Sheets("sheet1").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
   End If
cont4:
Next i

'//////////column m/////////////
ActiveSheet.Range("a1").Select
For i = 4 To lastrow
Range("m" & i).Select
If Range("m" & i).Value = "12/01" Or Range("m" & i).Value = "12/05" Then
GoTo cont5
Else

Rows(i).Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Cut
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select

        lrow = Cells.Find(what:="*", after:=[a1], searchorder:=xlByRows, _
    searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row


    Range("a" & lrow + 1).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    j = j + 1
    Sheets("sheet1").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
   End If
cont5:
Next i

'//////////column q and r/////////////
ActiveSheet.Range("a1").Select
For i = 4 To lastrow
Range("q" & i).Select
If Range("q" & i).Value <> " " And Range("r" & i).Value <> " " And Range("u" & i).Value <> " " _
And Range("z" & i).Value <> " " And Range("aa" & i).Value <> " " And Range("ab" & i).Value <> " " _
And Range("b" & i).Value <> " " And Range("j" & i).Value <> " " Then
GoTo cont6
Else

Rows(i).Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Cut
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select

        lrow = Cells.Find(what:="*", after:=[a1], searchorder:=xlByRows, _
    searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row

    Range("a" & lrow + 1).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    j = j + 1
    Sheets("sheet1").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
   End If
cont6:
Next i


End Sub
```