# Copy excel cell data to ppt textbox

Tags: excel, powerpoint, vba

I'm new to macro.
I have an excel sheet which has names in column A. I have a ppt with many slides. I need a macro in excel to take these names, create textbox in each slide and paste there one by one. Like, "A1" value should go to slide 1, "A2" value should go to slide 2...

Can anyone help in this.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to copy cell range as table from Excel to PowerPoint - VBA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3840370/how-to-copy-cell-range-as-table-from-excel-to-powerpoint-vba)

Answer (score 0):

For help automating Excel from within PPT or vice versa, visit my FAQ site, http://www.pptfaq.com and search the main page for any references to Naresh (that'd be Naresh Nichani, who wrote and allowed me to include a series of articles describing how to pull data from Excel or Access).  Study the code provided in his articles to learn how to pull data from Excel.

Then start with a single slide presentation with nothing but a text box on the first slide.
If you need something more complex than this, ask.

Sub MakeBradburySlides()
    ' You'd actuall fill the array from your Excel sheet
    ' but for demonstration purposes:
    Dim aData(1 To 5) As String
    aData(1) = "Something"
    aData(2) = "Wicked"
    aData(3) = "This"
    aData(4) = "Way"
    aData(5) = "Comes"

```
Dim x As Long
Dim oSl As Slide

With ActivePresentation
    For x = 1 To UBound(aData)
        Set oSl = .Slides(.Slides.Count).Duplicate(1)
        oSl.Shapes(1).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = aData(x)
    Next

    ' that leaves us with a blank slide at the beginning, so
    .Slides(1).Delete
End With
```

End Sub

If you prefer an off-the-shelf solution, I sell a PPT add-in that does all this and a lot more.  There's a free, fully functional demo at http://www.pptools.com/merge/