# how to paste table from excel to powerpoint 2007 as default using vba

Tags: vba, excel

I want to paste table from excel to powerpoint using vba.
I am using powerpoint version 2007.
I am able to successfully paste ppEnhancedmeta file.
But getting problem while pasting to ppPasteDefault.
** It gives error "Shapes (unknown member): invalid request. clipboard is empty or contains data which may not be pasted here**

```
Sub excel_to_powerpoint()     
Dim PPApp As PowerPoint.Application
Dim PPPres As PowerPoint.Presentation
Dim PPSlide As PowerPoint.Slide
Set PPApp = New PowerPoint.Application
PPApp.Visible = True
PPApp.Activate 
Set PPPres = PPApp.Presentations.Add
Set PPSlide = PPPres.Slides.Add(1, ppLayoutBlank)
Sheet2.Range("A1:C5").Copy
For i = 1 To 50000: DoEvents: Next
PPSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial ppPasteDefault
Set myshape = PPSlide.Shapes(PPSlide.Shapes.Count)
myshape.Left = 50
myshape.Top = 50
Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

Somebody have any idea where i am doing wrong.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figure it out.
I don't know where the problem occur.
But the solution that work for me is to replce 
    `PPSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial ppPasteDefault`
with
    `PPApp.ActiveWindow.View.PasteSpecial DataType:=ppPasteDefault`

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
PPSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial DataType:=ppPasteOLEObject, Link:=msoFalse
```

Instead of

```
PPSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial ppPasteDefault
```

This works for me on MS office 2010 however I don't have 2007 as you do so this may not work.

Found this code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3840370/how-to-copy-cell-range-as-table-from-excel-to-powerpoint-vba)

Hope it helps

Comment: Hi,    
@Mr.Burns : Thanks for ur reply.    
This code paste the table but it is edited not as simple as the simple table. The method used to edit is not so good.We need to double click table n then edit n also it will open table like in excel sheet.      
`PPSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial DataType:=ppPasteOLEObject, Link:=msoFalse`    
I want to paste table simple as we do manually.    
Thanks.

Comment: Hi,
Please help me.
I have tried many things. Nothing work :(
Thanks

Comment: Just to clarify are you wanting the code to paste the table into PowerPoint so it is blank or so that is still contains the information you entered into it?

Comment: Hi,
It contains information. I want to paste it in powerpoint to reduce manual task of copy & paste. 

Thanks for ur help.

Comment: Ok, I have tested the code a bit more and for it does paste the table in with any information that I entered, if you are wanting the code to keep the table updated in PowerPoint then I suggest you use formulas rather than code(=Index , =Match functions), Other than this I don't think I can help any more as the code works just not in the way you need it to

Comment: Hi,
`PPSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial ppPasteDefault`
This line work for u ?
Do i need to add some library for this to work.
Becoz in my case it does not do anything whie if i change it to `PPSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial DataType:=ppPasteOLEObject, Link:=msoFalse`. It works.
Is anything em missing ?

Comment: `PPSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial ppPasteDefault` doesn't work for me, as for why I do not know nor would I know what libarys to add for it to work saddly, if you feel you are missing something you can try using google to search for an answer, google has a wealth of knowlage out there, just need the paticent to look through it all

Comment: Burns. Thank u so much for ur help.